# Let pexcept Python script exit back into the actual bash

Tags: python, bash, pexcept

Can't really find proper information on this topic. I guess I'm searching for the wrong keywords, but it's probably not done much either.

What I would want to achieve is to let a Python run to auto-fill credentials each time I try to access my shell servers. The problem with a normal Python script doing that with Pexcept is that it only happens in that newly spawned shell.

Is there any way that something like this happens;

```
Last login: Wed Jan  1 23:06:53 on ttys001
macbook-pro:~ allendar$ ./auto_login user server
Connecting to the server..
Logging in..
Connected..
(exiting)
Last login: Wed Jan  1 23:04:32 2014 from zzz.zzz.com
root@svr01 [~]#
```

So what's actually would be happening is that the Python pexcept somehow hits the Bash that I am currently in and executes the commands from pexcept and then exits into that same Bash again.

I can also imagine a situation where I would actually end up into a newly spawned Bash. That wouldn't really matter.

So I'm not showing any code I have tried, because I don't really know how I would do it. I'm just curious if anyone has ever done something like this.

Comment: Wouldn't ssh keys be the way to go here ?  That being said, check out the 'interact' command in pexpect.

Comment: The problem is that some of our business servers have a weird issue, where (even if it's copyed) the auth-key won't validate. Most of them work tho. I just don't like to copy-paste passwords half of my workdays :P I'll look into the interact command thx.

Comment: Also note that depending on what you want to do, fabric (http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) is a python library for remotely executing commands which might be a better fit than pexpect